# "Invalid Host header" error when access AWS ECS through load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I used AWS ECS to deploy my docker app and after successful deployment I can access to the application with public IP address given without any problem.

But when I created an AWS load balancer for ECS and try to access with load balancer's DNS name I'm getting `Invalid Host header`.

What is the reason for this ?

My running docker containers,

- `nginx` at port 80
- `frontend` at port 3000
- `backend` at port 5000